# Error in `check_outcome()`: ! For a classification model, the outcome should be a factor

Tags: r, tidyverse, xgboost

I am setting up an xgboost model, but I am getting the error message:

> Error in `check_outcome()`: 
> ! For a classification model, the outcome should be a factor.

Despite making (and validating) that my outcome variable is indeed a factor.

```
train_set_prop = 0.8
set.seed(561)

df_num$kombucha_intake_num = as.factor(df_num$kombucha_intake_num)

train_test_split = rsample::initial_split(df_num, prop=train_set_prop, strata=kombucha_intake_num)
train = training(train_test_split)
test = testing(train_test_split)

xgb_fit <-
  boost_tree(trees=50) %>% # Specify that you wanted a boosted tree model
  set_engine("xgboost") %>% # Specify that you want to use xgboost
  set_mode("classification") %>% # Specify the "objective" is classification
  fit(kombucha_intake_num ~ ., data=train)
```

"Error in `check_outcome()`:! For a classification model, the outcome should be a factor. "

I did make (and validate) that my outcome variable is indeed a factor. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error for a factor variable and it was because I had some empty cells

Comment: Not sure how this wound up in the VLQ queue, but it's a legitimate attempt to answer the question. (Obviously, people are free to vote whichever way they want based on how useful they find the answer).